# Installing cordova-plugin-file-transfer breaks ajax requests for ios applications

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, cordova, plugins

**Install plugin**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

**Example ajax request**

```
$.ajax({
           url: 'https://www.reddit.com/.json',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function( data ) {
           alert( "SUCCESS:  " + data );
           },
           error: function( data ) {
           alert( "ERROR:  " + data );
           }
           });
```

No working here

**Remove plugin**

```
 cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Working here

**Question:** How to Fix

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: I've tested on iOS and Android and both of them work fine with or without the plugin

Comment: no errors. Thank you for testing i will try using other computer to testing (now i use virtual machine)